How to update Snowflake table without rewriting the table inside Python sheet - UDF
I have a Python worksheet on Snowflake and I am using this to deploy an udf. I want to add a update SQL inside this function but I believe I am missing something to find most efficient way.
When I use session.sql(update_query).collect() I am getting memory error:
SQL compilation error: Compilation memory exhausted.

Other methods I found from documents rewrites the whole table as I see and I do not want that since target table is very large.
Any thoughts?

Is the SQL update statement even working as a standalone query running in SQL worksheet?

Hi @LukaszSzozda yes it is working, but If it is possible I want to include it in udf


Can you simplify the update query?  2) Have you tried to use a larger virtual warehouse or Snowpark-optimized warehouse


@LukaszSzozda I had tried with 2×large and 4×large did not helped, will review query complexty again thanks

I found a workaround, still not sure if it's the best way.
It seems that when you call another procedure from within the worksheet, Snowflake waits for this process to finish before continuing with the rest of the code. I created a solution using this, I hope it will be useful to someone else:
def handler_function(session):

   #calculations on pandas

   session.sql(f"CALL MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_UPDATE_PROCEDURE()").collect()

   #other code

